# how to find number components dynamically such given in following Matlab code of PCA?

Tags: python, matlab, pca

In the following link fixed number of principal components analysis parameter is pre-defined but should be dynamically defined as Matlab code. How it is possible?

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

how to find the number of principal components dynamically such as given in Matlab code:

```
[coeff,score,~,~,explained] = pca(train);            
sm = 0;
no_components = 0;
for k = 1:size(explained,1)
    sm = sm+explained(k);
    if sm <= 99.4029
       no_components= no_components+1;
    end
end
no_components
```

here train variable is a 2D matrix.

Comment: Are you asking about something in Python or Matlab? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: yes, it should be in python

Comment: Which should be in Python? Is your question "how do I use PCA in Python?"? I can't exactly figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: here number of components is found depending on explained variable that i want in python code

Comment: yes, I want to above code in python

Comment: I see. In that case, please try this out for yourself and see how far you can get on your own. We can help you here when you have specific implementation questions, but we can't write code for you. The best way to learn is to try it yourself!

Comment: ok, the problem is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is slight variation with the explained variable with MatLab and python that I got so it is resolved as follow:

```
[x,y] = train.shape

pca = PCA(n_components=(x-1))
varPca = pca.fit(train)   

explainedVariance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_*100

sm = 0
no_components = 0
for k in range(0, x-1):
    sm = sm+explainedVariance[k]        
    if sm <= 99.4029:
        no_components= no_components+1    

print(no_components)
```